# Assigning Value to GridView in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, gridview, arraylist

Suppose we have a list

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}
```

We can easily assign `<asp:BoundField DataField="id " />` and call the Datasource in the Code behind file..this is ok
but if our List is like that

```
public class Entity

    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Payload payload { get; set; }
    }

public class Payload
{
    public string kloutId { get; set; }
    public string nick { get; set; }

}
```

you wrap up the Entity in a `List<Entity> l=new List<Entity>();`
but now what will we write in `<asp:BoundField DataField="?" />`
I tried to use kloutid, Entity.Payload.Kloutid, but that didn't worked out.Any one who can help me with this
Thanks in meekness :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following readonly property on `Entity`

```
public string PayloadKloutId
{ 
    get { return payload.kloutId; }
}
```

You'll be able to bind it like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PayloadKloutId" />
```

Comment: it doesn't run if you dont add set{} as well.Please edit it Thanks

Comment: @Mentor: that's not true :) you can have read only properties. What's the error it throws?

Comment: pardon me..There was another mistake that i associate with this.I appologize :) your answer is perfect